# Ansible task - how can I loop over all predefined vars to create linux groups in this format?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, jmespath

I have a predefined ansible variables, and I want to create linux groups from these variables.
The below task create only the groups in the first array *g1,g2,g3*
How can I loop over all lines to create other groups?

## The predefined ansible vars:

```
user_details:
  - { name: "user1", groups: 'g1,g2,g3' }
  - { name: "user2", groups: 'g4,g5' }
```

## The task as following:

```
- name: Create Group
  group:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ user_details.0.groups.split(',') }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jmespath`](https://jmespath.org/) and [`flattened`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/flattened.html) to retrieve all the groups and then `split` them by the delimiter `,`.

The loop would look like,

```
loop: "{{ lookup('flattened', (user_details | json_query(\"[*].groups\")) ).split(',') }}"
```

The outcome of this loop would be a list containing all the group names.

You might have to install the `jmespath` module to use the `json_query`

```
pip install jmespath
```

Comment: For performance sake, especially if your origin user list is large, you might want to add the [`unique` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) after the split so that the loop does not go over the same group several times.